# How to set textbox is blank for double datatypes in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using wpf application in MVVM Pattern, When I bind textbox with double datatype it always show default content "0" inside the textbox. how to set it blank when loading the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your double datatype to accept null value, like below,

```
double? name { get; set;}
```

so using "?" condition we can make any datatype to accept null, and assign this to your textbox.

Hope it is helps.